# Flickers while layout visible/gone

Tags: android, android-animation, visibilitychange

Is there any way to hide a view without flickering its above view?

I am trying to hide a View below **`MapView`**. Once I set its visibility to **`GONE`**, **`MapView`** flickers. As I have to add more markers dynamically, couldn't able to keep `MapView` and `bottomView` in `FrameLayout`, since the `bottomView` will hide those markers in small size screens.

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">


    <com.myapp.widgets.MapPlacePicker
        android:id="@+id/lay_fr_map_inc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/options_layout" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/options_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <com.myapp.widgets.FontTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Please select a location!!"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.aigestudio.wheelpicker.WheelPicker
                android:id="@+id/main_option_view"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                app:wheel_atmospheric="true"
                app:wheel_curved="false"
                app:wheel_item_space="15dp"
                app:wheel_item_text_color="#ffafafaf"
                app:wheel_item_text_size="12dp"
                app:wheel_selected_item_text_color="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:wheel_visible_item_count="3" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Output:**

[image: Flickers]

I have also tried **`TranslationAnimation`**, but no luck. Its showing more gray space than before.

```
        int fromY = (visibility == View.GONE) ? 0 : optionLayout.getHeight();
        int toY = (visibility == View.GONE) ? optionLayout.getHeight() : 0;
        if (visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
            optionLayout.setVisibility(visibility);
        }
        TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(
                0,                 // fromXDelta
                0,                 // toXDelta
                fromY,                 // fromYDelta
                toY); // toYDelta
        animate.setDuration(1000);
        animate.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        //animate.setFillAfter(false);
        animate.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                if (visibility == View.GONE)
                    optionLayout.setVisibility(visibility);
                optionLayout.clearAnimation();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
        optionLayout.startAnimation(animate);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any flickering in that animation; if you want to avoid the vertical resizing behavior of `lay_fr_map_inc` then you can just remove this attribute:

`android:layout_above="@+id/options_layout"`

...and maybe make the height `match_parent`. Then, `lay_fr_map_inc` will stay full height, but the bottom portion will be hidden by `options_layout` when it appears (instead of scooting upwards).

Don't forget to change the map padding when you do this, so you don't obscure the Google logo (which is a violation of the [rules](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/?__utma=102347093.1334913605.1531748723.1541197744.1541197744.1&__utmb=102347093.0.10.1541197744&__utmc=102347093&__utmx=-&__utmz=102347093.1541197744.1.1.utmcsr=google%7Cutmccn=(organic)%7Cutmcmd=organic%7Cutmctr=(not%20provided)&__utmv=-&__utmk=123873546&_ga=2.119107785.1397949078.1541197507-1334913605.1531748723)): [`setPadding()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setPadding(int,%20int,%20int,%20int))